# Python: Calling method A from class A within class B?

Tags: python, oop, class, wxpython

There are a number of questions that are similar to this, but none of the answers hits the spot - so please bear with me.

I am trying my hardest to learn OOP using Python, but i keep running into errors (like this one) which just make me think this is all pointless and it would be easier to just use methods.

Here is my code:

> ```
> class TheGUI(wx.Frame):
>     def __init__(self, title, size):
>         wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, title, size=size)
>
>         # The GUI is made ...
>
>         textbox.TextCtrl(panel1, 1, pos=(67,7), size=(150, 20))
>         button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click)
>
>         self.Show(True) 
>
>     def button1Click(self, event):
>         #It needs to do the LoadThread function!
>
> class WebParser:
>
>     def LoadThread(self, thread_id):
>         #It needs to get the contents of textbox!
>
>
> TheGUI = TheGUI("Text RPG", (500,500))
> TheParser = WebParser
>
> TheApp.MainLoop()
> ```

So the problem i am having is that the GUI class needs to use a function that is in the WebParser class, and the WebParser class needs to get text from a textbox that exists in the GUI class.

I know i could do this by passing the objects around as parameters, but that seems utterly pointless, there must be a more logical way to do this that doesn't using classes seem so pointless?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have several misconceptions.

1. You **are** using methods here. (Did you mean "functions", as in not belonging to a class?)
2. Classes are not some kind of container or namespace for functionality. They **define a data type**. The point of having the class WebParser is that you *can have more than one WebParser*.
3. In Python, classes are objects too. Right now, you aren't making `TheParser` be a `WebParser`; you are making it an alias for the class itself. In other words, `TheParser` is now equal to "the concept of a web parser", more or less.
4. Passing parameters around is not "pointless"; it's how you get information between functions. You don't (normally!) pass classes around; you pass around instances of the classes. Whether you use classes or not, you will have fundamentally the same communication problem.

It is very simple to fix this. First off, the WebParser needs to be created, so we take care of that by using its constructor. Next, our instance of `TheGUI` (a poor name btw - "the" doesn't really belong) needs to know about our instance, so we pass it to the constructor. That way, the instance can keep a reference to it, and use it to call the `LoadThread` method. It also needs to keep a reference to the `textbox`, so that this information can be passed along to `LoadThread`.

It looks like:

```
class MyGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, size, loader):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, title, size=size)

        # The GUI is made ...

        textbox.TextCtrl(panel1, 1, pos=(67,7), size=(150, 20))
        self.textbox = textbox
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button1Click)
        self.loader = loader
        self.Show(True) 

    def button1Click(self, event):
        self.loader.LoadThread(get_thread_id(), self.textbox)


class WebParser:
    def LoadThread(self, thread_id, a_textbox):
        do_something_with(a_textbox)


TheGUI = MyGUI("Text RPG", (500,500), WebParser())

TheApp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I appear to have the meaning of 'method' and 'function' mixed up. So a method is kinda like a function within a class? 
Thank you so much, i had the purpose of classes completley mixed up! It all makes much more sense now. So since there will only ever be one instance of the GUI and the Web parser, should i not use classes for these?

Comment: Also, does this mean i will have to feed every single class into MyGUI since all the other classes will have functions that are to be called upon a button press.

Comment: @Tommo, yes you should pass the objects to MyGUI. If you are passing a lot of objects then something else is wrong. It probably means you should combine some of your objects together.

Comment: Passing data around is a large part of the task of programming. But if it seems like it's too much or somehow "silly", maybe something more fundamental is wrong. Maybe you're assigning responsibilities to the wrong classes, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer to that problem is called [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller).

The Model is a representation of the data you want to present, in your case the state of the text RPG. The view is the component that handles the actual viewing on the screen. It gets the data it views from the model. The controller handles all input and other events that change the data and the view. This makes it pretty clear which object needs to know which.

Comment: It seems easier to just place all my code in the event handler for the button click, but that seems wrong!

Comment: @Tommo: it's easier the first ten or fifteen times; but once you start layering stuff on that way, it becomes a maintenance nightmare. Separating your code into clean classes is an up-front cost that makes it easier to trace down problems, make changes, and reuse code later.

Comment: @Tommo: It really depends. MVC gives you the flexibility to exchange or modify one each of the three components without affecting the others. You may think now that you do not need this, but one day you may decide that your text RPG could do with some graphics, or you want to try some fancy new API for all the web loading stuff, and then it would sure be handle to have loosely coupled components.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good sample code of the MVC model applied in wxPython at http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController