# Call function in wx.frame from different class in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, multiprocessing, nonblocking

There are very similar questions but I'm either not understanding them or they don't quite answer them.  The one two I have seen are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719185/python-calling-method-a-from-class-a-within-class-b) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891782/python-call-a-class-function-from-another-class).  I have a wxpython GUI running.  On the press of a button, I run four different threads (very long running tasks).  I have been able to implement this no problem -- the threads run and I can still use the GUI.

Each thread (`TestThread0`, `TestThread1`, etc.) writes a variable to a file (but never finishes its loop -- infinite loop).  Every so often (say every 20 seconds), I would like to run a function (`WriteThis`) in my main GUI application (wx.FRAME) that reads this file and its values/variables.  My question is how to run this function in the GUI part while the threads are still running?  My error comes into play when I try to run `TMainForm.WriteThis()`.

Below is my (very shortened) code:

```
class TMainForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):


            kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

            self.Splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)#, style=wx.SP_NOSASH)

            self.Panel1 = wx.Panel(self.Splitter, -1)          
            self.Panel3 = wx.Panel(self.Splitter, -1)

            self.Splitter.SplitVertically(self.Panel1,self.Panel3,400)

            ... and so on to set up GUI

    # Press button in GUI to run threads
    def OnAnalyzePress(self,event): 
        TestThread0()
        time.sleep(2)
        TestThread1()
        time.sleep(2)
        TestThread2()
        time.sleep(2)
        TestThread_output

    # This is the function I want to run from TestThread_output class below
    def WriteThis(self):
        print 'Running'
        # I will read file and update GUI here (Threads keep running though)

# Example thread (all the others are the same)
class TestThread0(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        # This is my "infinite loop" function that writes variable/values to a file
        MyLongRunningFunction.SomeFunction()

# This is the thread I want to run that executes some function in wx.FRAME every 20 seconds
class TestThread_output(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):

        for i in range(1000):
            TMainForm.WriteThis() # !!! This is where my error is !!! I want to run function called "WriteThis"
            time.sleep(20)

class TApplication(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):

            wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
            MainForm = TMainForm(None, -1,"")
            self.SetTopWindow(MainForm)

            MainForm.Show()
            return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application = TApplication(0)
    Application.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: you will need to make MainForm accessible to the threads (perhaps you could pass it in in the constructor) then in your thread you will need to call `wx.CallAfter(self.MainForm.WriteThis)`

Comment: I'm a little unsure on something (noob).  You say "Pass it in the constructor" -- I don't know what you mean.  I tried two things:  One was `wx.CallAfter(self.TMainForm.WriteThis)` and `wx.CallAfter(TMainForm.WriteThis)`.  The first gave me an error stating "'TestThread_output' object has no attribute 'TMainForm'" and the second gave me an error stating "unbound method WriteThis() must be called with TMainForm instance as first argument (got nothing instead)".  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TestThread_output(Thread):
    def __init__(self,mainForm):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mainForm = mainForm #save reference to the mainFrame GUI
        self.start()    # start the thread
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            wx.CallAfter(self.mainForm.WriteThis) #since its a diff thread you need callafter(or calllater)
            #I dont think you can do self.mainForm.WriteThis()
            time.sleep(20)

class TMainForm(wx.Frame):
    ...
    def OnAnalyzePress(self,event): 
        TestThread0()
        time.sleep(2)
        TestThread1()
        time.sleep(2)
        TestThread2()
        time.sleep(2)
        TestThread_output(self) #<- pass in this as mainFrame argument to thread constructor
```

Comment: Note: time.sleep() will block wx's MainLoop when called within wxPython, such as in the OnAnalyzePress() method. This will cause the UI to freeze and become unresponsive. It's fine to use time.sleep() in the thread though.

Comment: listen to mike... he is one of the best wx devs out there :P he also has an awesome blog that you have probably already used as a reference point

Comment: Yes, I've had to shorten the sleep times (i'm going to put a message up to indicate "updating".  Joran -- excellent response it works!  I have been following Mike's stuff -- It always helps me out.

Comment: I do something like `def smart_sleep(num_sec):t0=time.time();while time.time()-t0 < num_sec:wx.YieldIfNeeded()` typically if I really need a sleep

Comment: I don't think I've ever needed a sleep in my wx code...I use wx.Timers when I need to fire events periodically. There is a wx.Sleep(), but I haven't found much in the documentation that explains how this works...there's also FutureCall, which could be useful too.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the wx.Timers -- I will check that out!  Thanks!

Comment: I should point out the times ive needed a sleep are very few and far between and off hand I cant think of why I needed them